# Change CEPH dashboard url

Tags: ceph

Each time I go to 192.168.4.201 for my ceph dashboard, it redirects me to 192.168.4.204.

How do I make it go back to 192.168.4.201?

My setup:

```sh
root@storage1:/# ceph config set mgr mgr/dashboard/server_addr 192.168.4.201
root@storage1:/# ceph mgr services
{
    "dashboard": "https://192.168.4.204:8443/"
}
```

https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/mgr/dashboard/#host-name-and-port

Answer (score 1):

The host with the IP 192.168.4.204 is your active MGR in the cluster. Ceph automatically redirects all requests to the active MGR so in case of a failover you don't need to change the respective IP. You can test it: if you stop the MGR service on that host another MGR will take over.
There is also the command `ceph mgr fail <MGR>` which can be useful to fail a specific daemon (e. g. the active MGR). Since it's a stateless service you are fine running only two MGRs. In case of a failure (or tests) the other one takes over automatically.

Comment: Thanks @eblock, do you know how to change a node to a active MGR?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in my answer. Stop the mgr service on the active mgr node, this will cause an automatic failover and a different mgr will become active.

Comment: Let me rephase this, how would I make node 1 the master with out constantly failovering until it because active?

Answer (score 0):

Create file `mgr.yaml` with content

```
service_type: mgr
unmanaged: true
placement:
  hosts:
    - <mgr_server_hostname>
```

From [service specification](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/services/#service-specification):

> **unmanaged**
>
> If set to true, the orchestrator will not deploy nor remove any daemon associated with this service. Placement and all other properties will be ignored. This is useful, if you do not want this service to be managed temporarily. For cephadm, See [Disabling automatic management of daemons](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/services/#disabling-automatic-management-of-daemons)

Apply it with:

```
ceph orch apply -i mgr.yaml
```

To know machine hostname use this command on mgr machine:

```
echo `hostname`
```

**Optionally:**

Specify that you need only one mgr module

```
ceph orch apply mgr 1
```